# How can I handle this use case needing a FireStore calculated field? Can I use RxJS to generate it on client side?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am working on an Angular application storing data on Firebase Firestore database and I have the following doubt about what could be the best practice for the following use case.

The user fill a form for user registration inserting his\her personal data including his\her first name and surname. The user information are so saved into a **users** firestore collection. So in this collection I have something like this:

[image]

As you can see a **users** document contains the **firestName** and the **surname** fields.

Then into an Angular component view I have to show a users table (listing all the users saved in the previous collection). Into this table I need to put a "complete name" column containing composed values (firstName + " " + "surname"). This column have to be sortable so the best way is to have a **completeName** field into my model object:

```
export interface Employee {
    firstName: string;
    surname: string;
    completeName: string;
    placeOfBirth: string;
    socialSecurityCode: string;
    birthDate: Date;
    companyEmail: string;
    personalEmail: string;
    companyPhone: string;
    personalPhone: string;
    selectedEmployeeStatus: string;
    isEmployee: boolean;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Now my doubt is: what is the best way to set the **completeName** field of model objects implementing the previous interfaces? I found two possible solution:

1. I save also the calculated **completeName** field into my collection on FireStore (I use more database space...but I will have few records so it will be not a big issue).
2. Maybe I can use RxJS to calculate and set this value. In the specific case at the moment I have this service method retrieving documents from FireStore:

```
async getAllEmployees() {        
    return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)).valueChanges();
}
```

Instead directly returning my Observable how can I use RxJS to calculate the new field **completeName = firstName + " " + surname** for each object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to map values from response:

```js
return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)).valueChanges().pipe(
  map(employeeResponse => ({ completeName: employeeResponse.firstName + ' ' + employeeResponse.surname, ...employeeResponse }))
)
```

Comment: I am now obtaining this error message: "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'SlicePipe'
"

Comment: what is employeeResponse? it should be just object and we would return new object. cannot tell now without reproduction, need to debug